# How to declare instance of a class within a instance of class?

Tags: javascript, class

I am making a simple hmtl/js game. I'd like to have all the data of the Game in `DataofGame`. It is like tennis, it is simpler than tennis: there is only set and match. `changeinSet` is called on `click`.

But I think i have a problem with private variable so it doesn't work.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'WordsoftheGame' of undefined`

```
    //Added
    document.getElementById('playboutton').addEventListener('click', newGame);

    function newGame() {
        var DataofGame = new newGameData();
    }

    // New game
    function newGameData() {

        this.pointTeam1 = 0;
        this.pointTeam2 = 0;
        this.WordsoftheGame = ShuffleListe();
        this.ASet = new aSet();
    }

    //How the set is manage ********************

    function aSet() {
        var oneWord = DataofGame.ListeMot;
        // display the word and delete it from the list
        document.getElementById('jouer').innerHTML = oneWord[0];
        DataofGame.WordsoftheGame.shift();
        this.turn = true;
        this.score = 0;
    }

    function changeinSet() {
        DataofGame.ASet.score += 1;
        //This is the other team's turn:
        DataofGame.ASet.turn = !DataofGame.ASet.turn;

    };

    //shuffle liste
    ListOfWords = ['Artiste', 'Appeler', 'Cheval', 'Choisir', 'Ciel', 'Croire', 'Dormir'];

    function ShuffleListe() {
        data = shuffle(ListOfWords);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is not the variable, the problem is that you are using `this` when it is not supposed to be used. Can you show the full code of your class?

Comment: Thanks. What part of the code is not fully showed?

Comment: Could you declar e ListOfWords before instantiate your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function newGameData(){

  this.pointTeam1=0;
  this.pointTeam2=0;
  this.WordsoftheGame= ShuffleListe();
  this.ASet=new aSet();
}

//How the set is manage ********************

function aSet(){
  var oneWord=DataofGame.ListeMot;
  // display the word and delete it from the list
  document.getElementById('jouer').innerHTML=oneWord[0];
  DataofGame.WordsoftheGame.shift(); // << DataofGame not assigned yet
  this.turn=true;
  this.score=0;
}
```

Here when you're accessing `DataofGame`, it's not yet assigned because you're inside the constructor when calling `aSet()`.

What you want to achieve is not completely clear, but if it's adding an ASet method to your object, you could write something like this:

```
function newGameData(){

  this.pointTeam1=0;
  this.pointTeam2=0;
  this.WordsoftheGame= ShuffleListe();
  this.ASet = function() {
        // your code
  };
}
```

NB your coding style for names is a bit messy, you should use uppercases consistently. The usage is to start constructor names with uppercases, the rest in lower cases.

Comment: Ok tks. I think I will create 2 object. One for the all match 'dataofgame' and one for the set. Ok for the coding style : I stick to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: normal methods (and var): `shuffleListe`. Constructors: `NewGameData`. Constructors should stick out.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the function return an object with the data or just set the object.

```
function newGameData(){
    return { 
          pointTeam1 : 0,
          pointTeam2 : 0,
          WordsoftheGame : ShuffleListe(),
          ASet : new aSet() 
  }
}
```

But I would recommend to search for how to work with objects in javascript. Maybe this helps:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript